# Formatter function in XML view returns error

Tags: sapui5, formatter

I try to format the visibility property according to a custom parameter.

Element definition in the view:

```js
<CheckBox id="compensation0" selected="false" enabled="true" 
visible="{formatter: 'my.util.Formatter.visible'}"  editable="true" select=""/>
```

Formatter:

```js
my.util.Formatter = {
    visible: function(){
        return true;
    }
};
```

The error I get:

UIComponent.js:6 Uncaught Error: "[object Object]" is of type object,
expected boolean for property "visible" of 
Element sap.m.CheckBox #__xmlview1--compensationColumn

What did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but shouldn't the formatter expect also a `path` property (despite if you use it or not)?

Also, I would have expected your formatter to be written in AMD structure:

```js
sap.ui.define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    return {
        visible: function(value) {
            return true;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I'll update the code to AMD structure, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

BindingParser fails since you do not have a path property at your binding object definition. At the end you have an object for the boolean visible property which is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of the CheckBox contain errors: Try it in this way:

```
<CheckBox id="compensation0" selected="false" enabled="true" 
visible="{path: '', formatter: 'my.util.Formatter.visible'}" editable="true" select=""/>
```